# Find all values that one column's value has and collect as JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

| class_id | class | code | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | XYZ | A | 1 |
| 8 | XYZ | B | 2 |
| 9 | ABC | C | 3 |

I have a dataframe like above. I want to transform it so the 'codes' column below collects all the unique (code, id) pairs into a JSON format that a class contains.

| class_id | class | codes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | XYZ | [{'code: 'A', 'id': 1}, {'code': 'B', 'id': 2}] |
| 9 | ABC | [{'code: 'C', 'id': 3}] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach should works for you:

```py
import pandas as pd

records = {"class": ["XYZ", "XYZ", "ABC"], "code": ["A", "B", "C"], "id": [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (x[0], x[1].drop(columns=["class"]).to_dict(orient="records"))
        for x in df.groupby("class")
    ],
    columns=["class", "codes"],
)
```

Output:
[image]